# C programming. How to read input in my program that comes from another program (via pipe)?

Tags: c

Here is what I try to run:
(echo echo abc;echo echo def;echo echo ghi)|./myprogram

So input to myprogram comes from a pipe.

I am trying to read it as:

```
while (fgets(line, MAXLINE+1, stdin)){
...
}
```

But as I understand input that comes to my program is now stdin, right?
So it does not work. I am not sure how to change my program so it works with input that is coming from another program.

Thank you!

Comment: This *should* work.  That is, assuming `MAXLINE` is large enough, when run as shown, consecutive calls to `fgets` should produce `echo abc`, `echo def`, `echo ghi`, and EOF.  You say it does not work.  What happens instead?  Also, it would be very helpful if you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and followed that advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you posit is *exactly* how you should do it. By piping information into your program, it's mostly indistinguishable<sup>(a)</sup> from regular input, as the following transcript shows:

```
pax$ cat testprog.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
        char line[1000];
        while (fgets (line, sizeof(line), stdin)) {
                printf ("%s", line);
        }
        return 0;
}

pax$ gcc -o testprog testprog.c

pax$ ( echo echo abc;echo echo def;echo echo ghi ) | ./testprog
echo abc
echo def
echo ghi
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> There are ways to tell, such as with `isatty()` but you have to expend some effort. Mostly, input from a file or pipe or device can be treated as if you were entering it on the keyboard yourself.

Comment: hmm, I guess it was some issues with my Unix.. I did not change anything and it start working after a while. That is weird. Anyway, thank you!